# change format bootstrap-datepicker in same input text doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I've had some issues in my website...

when I change my radioButton, I wanna set my bootstrap-datepicker format to 'dd/MM/yyyy' or 'MM/yyyy' using just one input text field, but it doesn't work, someone can help me?

This is my javascript function below

```
function setDatePicker(value) {
    if (value === "D") {
        LimparCampo('date1');
        $('#datetimepicker1, #datetimepicker2').datepicker({
            language: 'pt-BR',
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            todayBtn: true
        });
    }
    else {
        LimparCampo('date1');
        $('#datetimepicker1, #datetimepicker2').datepicker({
            language: 'pt-BR',
            format: 'mm/yyyy',
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            todayBtn: true
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your function a callback on the 'change' event of the radio button? It would be helpful to share more of your code. It's possible that the error lies in how you've set up the event listener, or how this function gets called.

Comment: No, my radio button don´t have a callback, I´ve found the answer, and I´ll post here, maybe might help anyone..
Thank so much anyway ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve found the solution

I just use `$('#datetimepicker1, #datetimepicker2').datepicker('remove');`

Cya ^^